# Reform Rails - Validation - Wrong Number Arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, trailblazer, reform

I am trying out Reform using the `reform-rails` gem for the first time. I am trying to use it as a form object, do some validation and then persist it to the database. When I try to specify a validation it gives an error even when I try one of its own examples.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'reform'
gem 'reform-rails'
gem 'dry-validation'
```

config/initializerrs/reform.rb

```
require 'reform/form/dry'

Reform::Form.class_eval do
  feature Reform::Form::Dry
end

Rails.application.config.reform.validations = :dry
```

app/forms/album_form.rb:

```
class AlbumForm < Reform::Form
  feature Reform::Form::Dry

  property :name

  validation do
    required(:name).filled
  end

  property :artist do
    property :name

    validation do
      required(:name).filled
    end
  end
end
```

Command line:

```
AlbumForm.new(Album.new)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):1:in `<main>'
        2: from app/forms/album_form.rb:1:in `<main>'
        1: from app/forms/album_form.rb:6:in `<class:AlbumForm>'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))
```

Line 6 is `validation do`. Am I missing some thing?

Comment: Is that correct syntax? I think you dont need to wrap it with `params { ... }` inside `validation do .. end`.

Comment: @SampatBadhe Good question.. I thought I copied it from the docs... but looks different... going to replace it and see.

Comment: @SampatBadheThe issue still is there and is actually a support issue since I am using Ruby 3.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Reform (and Reform Rails) doesn't support Ruby 3. The update appears to be close for a release. All but one test passes. The test that fails appear to be related to Representable gem.

This is according to Yogesh Khater from the [Trailblazer - Reform thread at the Zulip Chat](https://trailblazer.zulipchat.com)